# How is one supposed to use tomcat with an existing project?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, server

I have on my hands an undocumented tomcat project with a bunch of java files (including what I assume to be the "main" server file) nested in a src folder and a "Web-content" folder whcih, somewhere inside a WEB-INF contains a web.xml file. I want to build and run this project but I'm at a complete loss as to how to do it.

I have at my disposal a terminal and some amount of common sense but those have failed me. Is there a simple way to do this ?

Comment: I think this will help you. http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/InstallTomcat/InstallTomcat.html

Comment: are you using eclipse IDE? if yes, create a Server on your eclipse for your tomcat. and then run the Project in that server you created.

Answer (score 0):

use both below links to understand the file structure and how to use tomcat:
http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/servlets/structure_of_java_web_application.php

http://crunchify.com/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-and-install-apache-tomcat-server-in-eclipse-development-environment-ide